# Do the Master/Slave Election happen in Broadcast Domain in OSPF? if not Why?

Tags: routing, ospf

According to my knowledge, Mater-Slave election is needed to decide who will to start communication between two routers. In broadcast domains all the DR other routers communicate with DR. Is there a need for M/S election here?

Please clarify.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The election is part of the process for database exchange.  Since every router in the broadcast domain creates a full adjacency with the DR and BDR, they determine a master/slave state with the DR/BDR.

Answer (score 0):

> ...In broadcast domains all the DR other routers communicate with DR. Is there a need for M/S election here?

Yes, a M/S election is needed. Since the router does not know how many neighbors are on the attached circuit it has to send LSA updates via multicast. On point-to-point Interfaces a unicast adress is used. This is one example why a M/S election is needed on broadcast and NBMA interfaces.

For this particular example I suggest reading the [OSPF Version 2 flooding procedure in RFC 2328](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328#page-148)